# How to increase chef time out ..?

Tags: chef-infra, knife, chef-windows

I need to install a software on windows 2008R2 machine which actually takes nearly 40 to 50 minutes .I am able to bootstrap and initiate the process. The installation has begun but after 30 minutes , chef is throwing an error .

```
ERROR: WinRM::WinRMHTTPTransportError: Bad HTTP response returned from server (500)
```

I want to know the status of that installation . Is there anyway to increase the timeout ..??

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from https://github.com/xebialabs/overthere#winrm-command-fails-with-a-500-response-code

> **WinRM command fails with a 500 response code**
>
> Multiple causes can lead to this error message:
>
> - If the command was executing for a long time, this might have been caused by a timeout. You can increase the WinRM timeout specified by
>     the winrmTimeout connection option to increase the request timeout.
>     Don't forget to increase the MaxTimeoutms setting on the remote host
>     as well. For example, to set the maximum timeout on the server to five
>     minutes, enter the following command:
>
>   ```
>   winrm set winrm/config @{MaxTimeoutms="300000"}
>   ```

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a timeout from Chef itself. It is just reporting that the server sent back an HTTP 500 (WinRM uses SOAP under the hood). Looking through the WinRM service docs there is a `MaxShellRunTime` that might be what you want, but the default value of that is 8 hours so probably not the timeout you are hitting.